# mod_proxy Fowarding Based on Request Host Header

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

Lets say I have 3 URLs and they all point to the same reverse proxy. I would like to have the requests being forwarded to the web servers behind the proxy based on the host header:

```
webfront1.example.com > reverseproxy.example.com > backend1.example.com
webfront2.example.com > reverseproxy.example.com > backend2.example.com
webfront3.example.com > reverseproxy.example.com > backend3.example.com
```

Based on what I have read, I can configure `reverseproxy.example.com/webfront1 > backend1.example.com, reverseproxy.example.com/webfront2 > backend2.example.com`, etc.

I am wondering if proxy based on host header is even possible or if I used the wrong approach entirely.

Comment: I am not entirely sure I understand your desired setup. Are `webfront1.example.com`, `reverseproxy.example.com` and `backend1.example.com` 3 different servers/machines?

Comment: sorry, i should have made it more clear... webfront1.example.com would be a cname in dns that points to reverseproxy.example.com and backend1.example.com is a different server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use name based virtualhosts for that. Example config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
ProxyRequests off

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName webfront1.example.com
  ProxyPass / http://backend1.example.com/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://backend1.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName webfront2.example.com
  ProxyPass / http://backend2.example.com/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://backend2.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that if you want to use SSL on reverseproxy.example.com, things become more complicated.